# Want to to get all available wifis signals strength level (-dbm) realtime in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, wifi, signal-strength

I want to get all available wifi signals' strength level (-dbm) realtime for each wifi with their Mac address. I have tried, the [wifi_hunter](https://pub.dev/packages/wifi_hunter) package. It was okay. but it doesn't allow me to fetch data in real-time. It's not the main problem. The main problem is this package crashes severely after 30-40 seconds of runtime. If anyone has any suggestions or ideas please let me know. Thank you.